# Нужен движок для копипаста

Tags: php, cms

Приблизительно, как на [CodePaste.ru](http://CodePaste.ru)
Вопрос в том, что я не могу его найти, и хотел бы узнать у людей, может кто его видел?

Comment: В чем вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что я не могу его найти, и хотел бы узнать у людей, может кто его видел?

Comment: Так почему бы это не указать сразу в вопросе?

Comment: Я считаю, что такой краткий заголовок не мешает раскрытию темы вопроса

Comment: Нужен движок гугла. Приблизительно, как на Google.ru  
Вопрос в том, что я не могу его найти, и хотел бы узнать у людей, может кто его видел?

Comment: @niki-timofe Не мешает, да, и уж точно не раскрывает. **Нужен уазик для поездок за грибами. Приблизительно как у соседа Васи.** Вот лично вам этот вопрос(если его можно так назвать) кажется интересным? Вызывает желание ответить?

Comment: Если я знаю дядю Васю, то почему бы не ответить?, темболее ссылка на дядю Васю в моём вопросе приложена XD

Comment: @Construct А вдруг всё - таки видел!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишите сами, нет такого вероятно.

Comment: В принципе есть, но они очень ограниченные (даже без админ - панели)
Легко сказать пишите сами. XD